# formik axios post form submission on reactjs

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Newbie in reactjs ,trying to build a simple form with formik and validating with Yup library .just got a problem ,how to submit axios post request in formik with validations shown in below code.i have confusion on handle submit function onSubmit

**CODE**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import config from '../../utils/config';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
     export default function AddCompanyPage = () => {
        let history = useHistory();
          const formik = useFormik({
          initialValues: {name:""}, 
           validationSchema : Yup.object().shape({
            name: Yup.string()
            .min(2, "*Names must have at least 2 characters")
            .max(20, "*Names can't be longer than 100 characters")
            .required("*Name is required"),
           }),
           onSubmit:values=>
          {
            const AddCompany=async e()=> {
              e.preventDefault();
              axios.post(`${config.APP_CONFIG}/Companies/Company`,values)
              .then(res => {
               if(res.data.status_code === 200){
                //setUser(res.data.msg)
                history.push("/settings/companies");
               }
               
             })
             .catch(err => {
              toast.error("Couldnot lpost data")
            }) 
             }
        },
      })
        return (
              <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Add a Company</h2>  
              <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}> 
                <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="Company">Company Name</label>
                  <input
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    value={formik.values.name}
                  />
                    
           {formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name ? (
             <div>{formik.errors.name}</div>
           ) : null}
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Please check your code for syntax errors before posting.

Comment: @tromgy i didn't find syntax errors and why it didn't works?

Comment: This doesn't look right: `function AddCompanyPage = () => {` -- you're mixing named and anonymous function. The return statement is not correct either.

Answer (score 0):

The approach seems fine, you can try correcting the syntax of the return statement. In the return statement you should return a single element, right now you are returning 2 elements, h2 and form.
You can try wrapping it in a wrapper class or a div (not the best approach).

Also remove the word function where you are declaring/exporting the component